# Oauth was rejected telling me my app needs to be live -- can't go live without approval

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am losing my mind. I can basically switch between "testing" and "in production" for my oauth configuration that I'm trying to use for my chrome extension.

It told me I cannot go "live" because I need approval because of my scopes. So I submit for approval, and I'm rejected because I'm not live. I literally don't have a clue what to do and I'm losing my mind. Please help.[image]

Comment: Does it really say they rejected your request because it wasn't "live"? Do you already have EVERYTHING they ask you for?

Comment: @JoshPart Yes, unless they left something out of the email, it is the only unmet requirement. Here is their email.

**It looks like your project Sheets Login (id: sheets-login) is a development or staging app. Development/staging projects, or projects which are not yet live to the public, are not eligible for verification.

We'll close this request and your project will have a status of ‘Rejected’ in your Google Cloud Console. This status won't affect your app's users, as long as your project is correctly set up for its use case.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from changing the status to "In production". The message is saying that you *also* need to verify your app after pushing it to production.

You can have a public app without verification. The caveat is that users will see this scary warning when they try to sign in with OAuth:

[image]

The purpose of the verification is to remove this message, and probably allow you to publish your app in the Chrome Web store since it's an extension, but before getting verified you still have to change the status to public.

I also recommend you check out their docs:

- [API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914)
- [Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)